# Populate Multiple Input Fields With Paramter From Url... (Half Working)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, auto-populate

So I have this simple form with 1 input field that populates the input field with a parameter from the url...

Here's the demo:
https://output.jsbin.com/wohegu?getmail=max@email.com

So as you can see, it populates the input field.

**THE PROBLEM**
I am using this form in a responsive page and there are 2 of these similar forms. As per the visitor's device, one of them gets hidden (display:none).

But this code only populates the first form's email input.

How can I edit the code so that it will populate all input fields with that particular class?

**THE CODE**

```
<input type='text' class='email_address' name='email_address' value=''>

var getmail = document.querySelector('input.email_address');
if (getmail) {
    var t = document.location.href.split('?')[1];
    if (t) {
        var params = {};
        var lst = t.split('&'), l = lst.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var p = lst[i].split('=');
            if (!p[1]) continue;
            params[p[0]] = p[1];
        }

        if (params.getmail) {
            getmail.value = params.getmail;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried document.querySelectorAll and document.getElementsByClassName but doesn't work with it...

Some direction please. :)

Thanks...

Comment: Instead of populating hidden element just populate visible matched element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get parameter value and populate inputs has class email_address & working with most major browsers.
**Note:** you should `encodeURIComponent` params value to be safe and

```
function getParam(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
if(input[i].className =='email_address'){
input[i].value = getParam('getmail');
}
}
```

Comment: Works like a dream! :)
Just one thing, if the input has multiple classes (they have couple for styling), it doesn't work? What can I do in that case? (Id's wouldn't work right?)

Comment: Ok got it working with id's, and also populates even if multiple forms with same id's...

Answer (score 0):

`.querySelector` selects only first matching element whereas `.querySelectorAll` selects all matching elements. So either make your css selector query such that it can become unique else use `.querySelectorAll` and then filter to the required element.

```js
var getmails = document.querySelectorAll('input.email_address');

if (getmails) {
    var t = document.location.href.split('?')[1];
    if (t) {
        var params = {};
        var lst = t.split('&'), l = lst.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var p = lst[i].split('=');
            if (!p[1]) continue;
            params[p[0]] = p[1];
        }

        if (params.getmail) {
           for(var i =0; i<getmails.length;i++)
            getmail[i].value = params.getmail;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type='hidden' class='email_address' name='email_address' value='' >

<input type='text' class='email_address' name='email_address' value=''>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input Vinayak, but your solution wouldn't help because users tilt mobile devices (landscape/portrait modes) so forms can get hidden and displayed on the fly. So I don't know if your code would work in that case? But still, thanks again for your precious time...

Comment: Nope, this is not working. Tried recreating on jsbin, doesn't work. And anyway, the above code by Egy worked for my situation...